# How do I copy dll files for a build using team build

Tags: tfs

I have a bunch of external dlls I use in multiple projects.  These dlls are referenced by these projects and everything compiles fine.

Now I am trying to get a Team Foundation Server build going for my projects.  When I run the build, it complains that it can't find the needed files.  How do I get TFS to find the needed files?

I was thinking I could use the copydirectory windows workflow function in a custom build template but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do things.  Also, if I do use copydirectory, how do I reference directories that reside on TFS rather than on the file system?  And where do I copy the files to?

Comment: what TFS version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:(if using 2010)
At the `Workspaces` tab you can `map the folder` that has all the DLLs you want, just make sure you reference the assemblies in your project appropriately.

For instance, if your project  is referring to the assemblies one level UP, before the project root folder, you may set the `workspace` like below:

$\Team Project\src -> $(BuildDirectory)\src

$\Team Project\dlls -> $(BuildDirectory)

Something like that should solve your issue.

There's also a way to do it in VS2010 build: You should add a copy command to the prebuild step for the project (select the project -> Properties -> Build Events).

If you want to use the windows workflow - template method, refer to this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2010/01/21/deep-dive-on-windows-workflow-4-0-activities.aspx

Comment: I've actually already tried to add the directory to the list in the "builddefinition:Workspaces->WorkingFolders" screen and it didn't work.  Also, regarding your idea to add custom build events, how could I reference files that exist on the TFS server?  I don't think doing that is possible.

Comment: Files existing in TFS server should be automatically cross-referenced when the activity will be triggered. I think may be you could try this then: `Build Definition`-> `Workspace` tab. Add the location in source control of your dll as server path and the local path, where you want your dlls to be downloaded. Its difficult to answer absolutely relevant to your needs, unless your question does describe much really how your server is all setup.

Comment: Alright, I was able to get things working using your method.  I guess I was just doing something wrong or using the wrong paths the first time I did it.  Thanks!